# Changing a segment's title color using androidplot

Tags: android, androidplot

I am drawing a pie chart and I wish to be able to change the colour of the text showing the title of the segments making up the pie chart. Currently the titles default to white and I am unsure where (if?) I can change it

Here is an example of my code:

```
Segment s1 = new Segment("percentage1",percentage1);   <-- I want to change the colour of the title here
Segment s2 = new Segment("" + 100 - percentage1 ,100 - percentage1); <--
```

I want to change the colour of the title here, too

```
mPieChart.addSeries(s1,new SegmentFormatter(Color.parseColor(colourString), Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT));

mPieChart.addSeries(s2, new SegmentFormatter(Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

There doesn't seem to be anywhere to define what colour I want the title text for the segments to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can setting with line: labelPaint.color="@color/tagGrey", this color you can define in xml file, example: pie_segment_format.xml, where xml file contains:

```
<config
fillPaint.color="@color/tagRed"
labelPaint.textSize="10dp"
innerEdgePaint.color = "@color/tagRed"
outerEdgePaint.color = "@color/tagRed"
radialEdgePaint.color= "@color/tagRed"
linePaint.strokeWidth="0dp"
labelPaint.color="@color/tagGrey"/>
```

Then you must create the segment formatter, like this:

```
SegmentFormatter segmentFormat = new SegmentFormatter();
segmentFormat.configure(this, R.xml.pie_segment_format);
```

And finally setting that format:

```
mPieChart.addSeries(s1, segmentFormat);
```

Sorry by my english, I hope thist information can help you  ...